# Variable value is not working while using as action

Tags: javascript, split, click, element, testcomplete

I want to make a click on element using java script. Actual code to be click is as following which is working fine if I am using as it is. `Aliases.LateralData_Applications_Dashboard.LoginForm.btnOK.ClickButton();`

I am taking values from table in to 2 different string as following.  `Aliases.LateralData_Applications_Dashboard.LoginForm.btnOK`

and 
`ClickButton();`

Now I am trying to make click using combination of these 2 strings which is not working.

```
  var tblObjectrepo = new db_Acess_connect();
  var tblTestSteps  = new db_Acess_connect1();
  var elementPath=tblObjectrepo.field1;  // getting value as Aliases.LateralData_Applications_Dashboard.LoginForm.btnOK
  var elementAction=tblTestSteps.field1; // getting value as ClickButton
  elementPath.elementAction; // this part of code is not working
  Log.Message("Final Click: "+elementPath+"."+elementAction+";"); value is displaying as Final Click: Aliases.LateralData_Applications_Dashboard.LoginForm.btnOK.ClickButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var expr = elementPath + "." + elementAction + "()";
eval(expr);
```